# SQL Server 2014 Exploding Dates show only year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got this data from my table:

```
id    arrival_date   departure_date
1     2017-10-10     2017-10-15
2     2017-11-16     2017-11-30
3     2017-10-14     2017-10-31
4     2018-05-12     2017-05-22
5     2021-01-16     2021-03-15
6     2018-06-02     2017-07-02
```

All i want is to explode these date but i only want to show the year only

```
date
2017
2018
2019
2020
2021
```

these should be the once that I wanted to see is their any query for these?
Note: if this year is 2018 it should start in 2018, so i will use getdate() in that instance, i want to get the max in departure_date part, can I do that?

Comment: What is the schema definition for your table? Are these strings or actual date / datetime / or datetime2 types?

Comment: @igor these are only date data type

Comment: Have you tried `YEAR`?

Comment: yep but the thing is how can i explode these? should I while or something loop?

Comment: Extract is your friend. http://modern-sql.com/feature/extract  And what do you mean by "explode"?

Comment: what do you mean by explode? what i see from your example is you get the least year in any date columns and the max. then get years from min year to max year..

Comment: @MarkusWinand EXTRACT is not a valid sql server function.

Comment: @GeomanYabes after I get the min and the max should i use loop?

Comment: You have been asked repeatedly what you mean by "explode". Do you want every year between the earliest year from both columns and the latest year from both columns? And no, you do not want to use a loop. You want a tally table. I will show you once I understand what you want.

Comment: @SeanLange my question is finally answered :)

Comment: Next time @GGw, you should fully describe your question and please.. don't use words only you can understand. Also, if you want to ***"explode"*** something, you should ask questions to the terrorist forum, not here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a recursive cte

```
DECLARE @maxYear INT 
SELECT @maxYear = MAX(YEAR(departure_date)) FROM YourTable

;WITH cte
AS
(
   SELECT YEAR(GETDATE()) AS [Year]
   UNION ALL
   SELECT [Year] + 1
   FROM cte
   WHERE [Year] < @maxYear
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/SHJBX20252)**

Comment: this answers my question :)

Comment: This works but be careful. Using a recursive cte to count like this looks set based but in reality it isn't. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/

Answer (score 1):

Just use `YEAR(arrival_date)` and `YEAR(departure_date)`

Comment: I get this but the thing is I want to explode it, I want the output to be like the 2nd part